# how to convert function into es6 arrow function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

i need to write below function into arrow function using ES 6 . below i have given function.in reactjs

//

```
        tab_Row(){
          return this.state.business.map(function(object, i){
              return <Table_Row  />;
          });
        }
```

Comment: It’s not just a function but a method.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way -

```
 tab_Row = () => {
          return this.state.business.map((object, i) => {
              return <Table_Row  />;
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the ES-6 Syntax for the above like this

```
 const tab_Row = () => {
          return this.state.business.map((object, i) => {
              return <Table_Row  />;
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly was the issue which you couldn't figure out?

```
   tab_Row = () => {
          return this.state.business.map((object, i) => {
              return <Table_Row  />;
          });
        }
```